# Trying to create a timer to pause a loop in python

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, motion

Here I go messing with timers and motion sensors again.

I have a PIR motion sensor connected to a raspberry pi. I want to have the motion sensor have a cooldown of one minute before it checks for motion again.  I've been messing around with threading some... but I don't think I need that for this and would like to keep it simple.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 11
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

motion_cooldown = 60
start = 0

while True:
    if(time.time() < start + motion_cooldown):
        print("cooldown")
    else: 
        if PIR_PIN == 1:
            print("motion detected")
            #do some stuff
            start = time.time()
        elif PIR_PIN == 0:
            print("no motion")
            #do some stuff
            start = 0         #reset start to 0 so the loop continues
```

The current error I'm getting is " '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method and int" I assume that means I can't compare an int and the time.time() but I swear of done similar before and it worked fine.  Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: `timer.time()` where is the `timer` object from? `time.time()` gives a time  in float fwiw

Comment: That was a typo in the question.  My code has time.time() in it.  Will edit my question to correct.

Comment: your code works if that is the case, I copy pasted (not getting the error you mentioned) and made the change and I get an infinite loop, if the question is about making the loop pause then add `time.sleep(60)` at the end of the loop

Comment: what you mentioned is likely to happen if you have `start = time.time` instead of `start = time.time()`, but as pointed out your code works fine

Comment: I should have mentioned I need to avoid using time.sleep as it pauses the whole program and  I have other sensors I need to incorporate.  I'll check my code again, however.   I'm testing it in the Thonny ide if that makes a difference.

Comment: The missing parenthesis fixed it!  I just need to fix my logic on the infinite loop part and I think I know what to do!  Thanks!

Comment: you can accept the answer below if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to happen if you have not called the function, that is when you do something like `start = time.time`, but your code does not do that, and it is not reproducible. For pausing the loop you can use `time.sleep(60)` at the end of the `while` loop